# A negative binomial-ish probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose you have a biased coin favoring heads with probability $0.5 < p < 1$. Define the $\mathit{net \; win}$ to be the number of heads minus the number of tails. Let $\alpha, \beta \in \left\{1,2,\ldots\right\}$. Define the random variable $X$ where one flips the biased coin indefinitely until the net win reaches either $-\alpha$ or $\beta$. What is the probability of reaching $-\alpha$? How about reaching $\beta$?

I was thinking of using the negative binomial distribution here, however, that does not seem to consider the termination of the trials when it either reaches $-\alpha$ or $\beta$.

Comment: Your `net win` starts at `0`. So do you want $\alpha < 0 < \beta$?

Comment: Oh yes. That's what I meant. Let me edit it. Thanks

Comment: This is a version of [Gambler's ruin with an unfair coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin#Unfair_coin_flipping)

Comment: @doge5ever does my answer cover your queries? Henry's link is also very useful, giving the answer. I suggest that you go through _both_ methods so that you understand best how to approach these types of questions in the future! `:-)`

Comment: Both approach works well in fact! Henry's solution is a quick solution, and I will be needing deeper analysis using your solution. Thanks @SamOT and @Henry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be a $p$-biased SRW on $\mathbb Z$, with positive drift. Then the net win $N$ satisfies $N_n = X_n - n$, where $n$ is the number of coin tosses.

You will be able to solve your question using martingales. See, for example, Chapter 2 in here: [http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Lectures/ap.pdf](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejames/Lectures/ap.pdf). Proposition 3.1.4 there is very related to your question.

Let me outline the general approach. Let $\tau$ be the time you hit $\alpha$ or $\beta$.

- Use a martingale based on $X_n$ to find $\mathbb E(\tau)$.
- Use a martingale based on $X_n^2$ to find $\Pr(X_\tau = \alpha)$.

---

@Henry points out in the comments that unfair Gambler's ruin is actually covered on the relevant Wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin#Unfair_coin_flipping.